# select specific date format in jpa criteria query

Tags: date, jpa, criteria-api

I want to select date in particular format in multiselect of jpa criteria query
like we use

```
select to_char(tn.dbdate,'yyyy-MM-dd') from transaction tn
```

in oracle.

I am able to use

```
query.multiselect(cb.function("TO_CHAR",String.class,transaction.get("dbdate")) );
```

but this returns date in database format i.e.

`Wed Apr 2 12:20:50 2014`

but how to get this in specific date format

`'yyyy-MM-dd'`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In current query no format is given as an argument to TO_CHAR function. That's why it cannot do much else than fall back to default. As [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#function%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression...%29), more than one arguments can also be passed to database function via CriteriaBuilder.function:

```
query.multiselect(
    cb.function("TO_CHAR",
                String.class,transaction.get("dbdate"), 
                cb.literal("yyyy-MM-dd")));
```

Comment: thanks but I had tried this.its showing compilation error for cb.function() method.There should be some expression instead of string at place ('yyyy-MM-dd').

Comment: Right, cb.literal should be used to have format as Expression<String>.

Comment: Thanks alot ... cb.literal() solves my problem. its working now :)

Comment: Not working for me ..getting error as   NameError: no method 'function' for arguments (org.jruby.RubyString,org.jruby.Ru
byClass,org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.SingularAttributePath,org.hibernate.ejb.
criteria.expression.LiteralExpression) on Java::OrgHibernateEjbCriteria::Criteri
aBuilderImpl

Comment: Instead of "yyyy-MM-dd" try "%Y-%m-%d". Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153144/how-to-search-date-field-for-a-string-using-jpa-criteria-api

Answer (score 0):

You can take the date from DB and format it as you want later.

Comment: No, I am not using custom classes i.e. i need to show directly as fetched from database.
So need to format in query only

Comment: Can you use native query that makes to_char(tn.dbdate,'yyyy-MM-dd')?

Comment: yes i can but that is not the solution.there is need of solution in JPA criteria or JPQL

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Expression<String> dateStringExpr = cb.function("to_char", String.class,
        root.get("effectiveStartDate"), cb.literal("YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS"));

ls.add(cb.like(cb.lower(dateStringExpr), "%" + effectiveStartDate.get().toLowerCase() + "%"));
```